# Error "cannot open display" on systemd Service which needs graphical interface

Tags: systemd, boot, services, startup

I wanted to send a popup on boot with zenify:

```
zenity --info --text="`hostname -I`" --title="Rpi Local IP" --display=:0.0
```

So here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Display IP at boot
After=networking.service graphical.target
Wants=networking.service graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'zenity --info --text="`hostname -I`" --title="Rpi Local IP" --display=:0.0'

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

An error occured everytime:

```
raspberrypi bash[530]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
raspberrypi zenity[530]: cannot open display: :0.0
```

**If I add like 10 seconds of sleep before starts my service :** `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10`, **everything works well**.

Where is my mistake ?

Thank you :) !

Answer (score 4):

Finally managed thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg) post.
Let's say my service file will be "boot_ip.service".
First of all, don't create the service as a system service but as a USER service.

Here is the service file `~/.config/systemd/user/boot_ip.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=bootIp
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'zenity --info --text="`hostname -I`" --title="Rpi Local IP" --display=:0.0'


[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

Then create a file called `~/.config/systemd/user/xsession.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Xsession running
BindsTo=graphical-session.target
```

This file will indicate that the graphical environment is ready.

Then create a file called `.xsessionrc` (if I create file `.xsession` as mentionned in the topic, my graphic environement is broken and I can't even do a simple login so be careful):

```
systemctl --user import-environment PATH DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
systemctl --no-block --user start xsession.target
```

This file will be executed once the user is logged in. As you can see, this file will start `xsession.target` and this will start our service `boot_ip.service`, problem solved ;) .

Comment: sorry i voted this up -- but now i tried it and it doesn't work (unit script still does not have access to display)